# JetBrains IDEA 2016.1.3: how to stop show warning “unresolved function” on “Promise.then” method?

Tags: javascript, warnings, es6-promise, jetbrains-ide

## TLDR

How to stop IDEA warns `unresolved function` on `Promise.then` from required files?

## Description

How can i fix this?

if I declare `Promise` and use it at the same file, it`s OK, no warnings. But if I declare promise at one file and use it at another file, IDEA shows me a warning `unresolved function`.

Surely I can just turns off this warning type, but I need to see such warnings in other places, where the real problems are.

## Example

I declare `Promise` at `foo.js` and require it at `bar.js` like below.

**foo.js**

```
'use strict';

function foo () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(true);
  });
}

module.exports = foo;
```

**bar.js**

```
'use strict';

const foo = require('./foo');

function bar () {
  foo().then().then();
}

module.exports = bar;
```

Show me a warning on 1st `then` method of foo`s promise.

[Image: There is a clearly warning (curly line) on 1st `then`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TExCa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSDoc:

```
/**
 * 
 * @return {Promise}
 */
function foo () {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      resolve(true);
});
}
```

works for me

Comment: Oh, this works, but it change one visual garbage at code to another one. 
Totally not a soluton I looking for.